# Failed to transform firebase-firestore-24.1.2.aar - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase

When I try to run in a real Android device I get this error, But it runs successfully on browser.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform firebase-firestore-24.1.2.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find firebase-firestore-24.1.2.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.2).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.1.2/firebase-firestore-24.1.2.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-appcheck-interop-16.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-interop:16.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-appcheck-interop-16.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-interop:16.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-appcheck-interop/16.0.0/firebase-appcheck-interop-16.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/20.1.1/firebase-common-20.1.1.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/20.1.1/firebase-common-20.1.1.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/20.1.1/firebase-common-20.1.1.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-common-20.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/20.1.1/firebase-common-20.1.1.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-database-collection-18.0.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-database-collection-18.0.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-database-collection/18.0.1/firebase-database-collection-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/18.0.1/play-services-base-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/18.0.1/play-services-base-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-base-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/18.0.1/play-services-base-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.1/play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.1/play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.1/play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.1/play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.1/play-services-tasks-18.0.1.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/18.0.0/play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/18.0.0/play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/18.0.0/play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/18.0.0/play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/18.0.0/play-services-basement-18.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-components-17.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-components-17.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-components/17.0.0/firebase-components-17.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-components-17.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-components-17.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-components/17.0.0/firebase-components-17.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform firebase-components-17.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find firebase-components-17.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-components/17.0.0/firebase-components-17.0.0.aar
   > Failed to transform protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/protolite-well-known-types/18.0.0/protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting minSDKVersion to 19 fixed my problem.